# I have a question about laravel migrations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a group project. I made some changes to the database migrations and tried to 'php artisan migrate:fresh' but I get an error. I am working with homestead and its up and running. The first file is my .env file and the second file is the error I'm getting. Thanks in advance!

---

```
    //.env file
APP_NAME=personeelsfeest51
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:9iWWmdKCm36jsC6qus8RaVtzM2ZQpFwb1+fTbGZx/s0=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://localhost:3000

    LOG_CHANNEL=stack

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=33060
    DB_DATABASE=ProjectPHP-51
    DB_USERNAME=homestead
    DB_PASSWORD=secret

    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_LIFETIME=120

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    AWS_BUCKET=

    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
    PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

    MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
    MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

---

```
C:\sites_laravel\TEST\ProjectPHP-51>php artisan migrate
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ProjectPHP-51 and table_name = migrations
 and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
  at C:\sites_laravel\TEST\ProjectPHP-51\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] ")
      C:\sites_laravel\TEST\ProjectPHP-51\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:382)")
      C:\sites_laravel\TEST\ProjectPHP-51\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:27

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Is your port right? `DB_PORT=33060` seems wrong (by default it's `DB_PORT=3306`, you've got an extra 0)

Comment: Try with `DB_DATABASE="ProjectPHP-51"`. Database name with quotes...

Comment: @GiuServ I don't think that's it, since the error message clearly contains the database name: `where table_schema = ProjectPHP-51`

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL error of [2002] is a refused connection. Try some of the following:

1) Check that MySQL is running on your homestead installation

```
sudo service mysql status
```

2) Check that your environment file is either not cached or up to date:

```
# Clears the config cache entirely and will read directly from the config files
php artisan config:clear

# Re-caches all config files
php artian config:cache
```

3) Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

4) Restart / re-provision your homstead box

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: I already fixed it, the problem was that I had a mysql server installed that was running on the same port (33060). When I stopped the MySQL service, everything worked fine. Thanks anyway for the effort!

Comment: No probs, glad you got it sorted!